# Gmail send as alias / replacement service

Tags: email, gmail

Gmail used to have a setting to send email from a different email address which I used extensively. I have numerous domains with email forwarding - they all forward into a Gmail account and the the Gmail account can send as various email addresses from those domains.

It seems Gmail has now stopped this service and to send as an alias you need to have an SMTP server for your domain - something I don't have and would have to pay for on a per-domain basis annually.

Does anyone have any suggestions or recommendations for other email services that provide a similar service if I was to bin Google and go elsewhere.

Comment: I use Thunderbird as a POP3 client with several e-mail servers, using Gmail as the SMTP server for most of them, and I find that by configuring the Thunderbird accounts and SMTP servers I can get the headers I want on the non-Gmail accounts. I configure several accounts with the same log-in credentials, but different identities. I have to down-load from all the e-mail servers into my local machine, rather than using Gmail to fetch them, so I need to include the Thunderbird folders in my own back-up regime instead of relying on Google to back up the non-Gmail accounts for me.

Comment: Will Gmail let you send as any email address through their SMTP servers?

Comment: It would seem so: I certainly use non-Gmail addresses.